# How to use href in CONTENT css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, href

I have the a box as follows :

[image]

On hover of the above box, the box flips to this:

[image]

This is the HTML code for the block:

```html
<div class='tiles'>
  <div class='col'>
    <a href=""></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href=""></a>
    <div class='box'></div>
  </div>
```

I am using CSS to display before and after values using `content`:

```css
       .col:nth-child(2) .box:before {
        content: "Maps Available";
        background: #e4a001;
        }
        .col:nth-child(2) .box:after {
          content:' Google Map : Click    \A'
          'Apple Map: Click \A  \A';

          background:#e4a001;
        }
```

Now in the above code , I want to include 'href' such that when the user clicks on 'click'(as can be seen in second pic) the user is directed to google & apple maps accordingly. I tried to use attr(href) but it doesnot work. I also understand that we cannot put href in CSS .
**I understand that CSS cannot be used to achieve this. IS there any alternative out there ??**
 Any help is welcome.

Comment: You cannot create a link with css - css is for styling

Comment: flip animation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because this cannot be done using css

Comment: I understand that CSS cannot be used . As I myself have mentioned that href cannot be included in css. I am searching for an alternative and so I have come here.

Comment: Just put the text in the `<a>` tags and show / hide them as you need. Don't use `:before` / `:after` at all.

Comment: @SagarKodte yeah

Comment: @JAne. where you made flip animation? you need to two div that is front side and second side and then on second side you can add anchor

Comment: @Toastrackenigma please help. I kind of understand what you are saying , but there are many box like these , each with different content and I need to add urls in almost all.

Comment: Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/tvaz7jtw/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just show and hide the links as you need:

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  position:fixed;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.front, .back {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  transition:transform 0.5s linear;
  background-color:#f44336;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.back {
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.box:hover .front {
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.box:hover .back {
  transform:rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="front">
    Maps
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    Google Map: <a href="http://www.google.com">Click</a>
    <br><br>
    Apple Map: <a href="http://www.apple.com">Click</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.I tried this but it didnot help . Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/tvaz7jtw/3/

Comment: @JAne You're fiddle doesn't seem show anything on my browser. What are you trying to accomplish? Is it similar to what's in my code snippet?

Comment: have included the box just to give you guys an idea of what the situation looks like at my end. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please drag the  below window  in the fiddle UP to see the box

Comment: @JAne I've updated my answer too. This should do exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I get it now .